# vim make COLOR of user defined type same as basic type in C++

Tags: c++, vim, colors, highlight, color-scheme

I am trying to use vim as my C++ editor. But I find that it only highlight the basic C++ type (e.g. `int, double`) as some color.

For user defined type or class, it does not give a color. I would like the **color** of **user_defined_type** in `user_defined_type & a` has the same color as the **int** in `int & a`.

Is there any solutions or suggestions?

Best,
Zhihao

Comment: It will take some setup on your part. Here's the first step https://github.com/vim-scripts/TagHighlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several plugins that support this. Here's the first couple I found:

- [User Defined Type Highlighter](https://github.com/vim-scripts/User-Defined-Type-Highlighter)
- [vim.cpp - additional vim c++ syntax highlighting](https://github.com/octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight)

Just pick one and install it. If you haven't used Vim plugins before, I recommend installing a Vim package manager such as [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) (which is about 5 steps under the [Quick Start](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start) on that page). It will make the process painless.

Happy vimming!